# Unable to rename ios application via CFBundleDisplayName

Tags: iphone, ios, rename

I want to change the application name that shown below is app icon. but i am unable to do this from info.plist file.

I have tried changing following value:

Bundle display name:${PRODUCT_NAME} ==> Bundle display name:${MyApp}.

But it didn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app name doesn't need to be surrounded by `${}`

> My App

instead of

> ${MyApp}

If you are changing the value in the default view for the plist, it should look like this:

[image]

Including the `${}` indicates that the plist should get the value with key "MyApp" from the build settings.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this by renaming the  project name which lead me to troubles. Thats why i am afraid of experimenting. Thanks you for such quick ans :)